# static images in vue electron are not processed by webpack

Tags: vue.js, webpack, electron

I have an `electron-forge` application where I'm using webpack and Vue.js. I'm facing an issue with Vue.js where the image paths in the `src=""` attribute of `.vue` files are not being translated.

For example:

**index.html**

```
<img class="technology" src="/resources/images/logo-github.png">
```

in final program, path will be displayed as:

```
<img class="technology" src="/7805c4becec378a9d938.png">
```

but in

**example.vue**

```
<li><img class="technology" src="/resources/images/logo-nodejs.svg"></li>
```

path will be displayed without any changes. As a result, the images are not displayed, and I get a 404 error.

I am using these webpack rules:

**webpack.rules.ts**

```
import type { ModuleOptions } from 'webpack'

export const rules: Required<ModuleOptions>['rules'] = [
  // Add support for native node modules
  {
    // We're specifying native_modules in the test because the asset relocator loader generates a
    // "fake" .node file which is really a cjs file.
    test: /native_modules[/\\].+\.node$/,
    use: 'node-loader',
  },
  {
    test: /[/\\]node_modules[/\\].+\.(m?js|node)$/,
    parser: { amd: false },
    use: {
      loader: '@vercel/webpack-asset-relocator-loader',
      options: {
        outputAssetBase: 'native_modules',
      },
    },
  },
  {
    test: /\.vue$/,
    use: {
      loader: 'vue-loader',
    }
  },
  {
    test: /\.tsx?$/,
    exclude: /(node_modules|\.webpack)/,
    use: {
      loader: 'ts-loader',
      options: {
        transpileOnly: true,
      },
    },
  },
  {
    test: /\.(html)$/, 
    use: {
      loader: "html-loader"
    }
  },
  {
    test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)$/i,
    type: 'asset/resource'
  },
  {
    test: /\.(mp3)$/i,
    type: 'asset/resource'
  }
]
```

Comment: Hav you tried the global import with @ (reference to src forlder).
```<img class="technology" src="@/resources/images/logo-github.png">```

Comment: @RaphaelRlt I have found that if I copy the entire directory `resources` into the final project using the `CopyWebpackPlugin`, the paths work fine. But then images wont be processed by webpack and I dont need that test rule for images I think :/

Comment: **UPDATE:** It looks like using `<li><img class="technology" :src="require('/resources/images/logo-nodejs.svg')"></li>` solved my issue and now it works fine ... but why?

Comment: Is the second thought i would have.
Because require() is used by webpack, and it resolves the import dynamically :)